# Export duplication classes

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, code-duplication

I have a question regarding extraction of duplication classes in SonarQube.

Namely I've noticed that the only way that you can get an overview of code clones is by clicking on the left bar next to a duplicated fragment.

However, I would like to extract this information either from the MySQL database or as a report.

Like for example, let's assume we have a code fragment in class A. This fragment was cloned to classes B, C, D, E. Then I would like to extract something like: Code fragment X of class an appears in classes B, C, D, E.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [duplications web service](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/duplications/show). You'll have to synthesize the report you want, but this should provide the data.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!